# Text Exceeds Grid Size

Tags: html, css

```css
/* I have a grid inside another grid. The parent grid is set as follows: */

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2.409fr 2.409fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 5.5fr 5.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header sidePanel" 
    "pageContent pageContent sidePanel" 
    "pageContent pageContent sidePanel" 
    "footer footer sidePanel";
}


/* the pageContent class contains another 2x2 grid, with three elements: */

.content {
  grid-area: pageContent;
  background: #d123;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "content-1 content-2" 
    "content-1 content-3";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.sidePanel {
  grid-area: sidePanel;
}

.content {
  grid-area: pageContent;
}

.content-1 {
  grid-area: content-1;
}

.content-2 {
  grid-area: content-2;
}

.content-3 {
  grid-area: content-3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">My Header</div>
    <div class="sidePanel">My sidePanel</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-1">
        <span class="title">Main Article</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum rem ratione dolorum ducimus quaerat officiis voluptates obcaecati ab illo sequi, blanditiis vel dolore possimus labore asperiores architecto quia nobis accusantium beatae doloremque
          eveniet saepe excepturi laborum exercitationem delectus! Dolor, natus perferendis deleniti sequi veniam. In nemo mollitia dolor ipsam. Ipsa illum delectus eveniet. Explicabo perspiciatis eum distinctio vel quo iure, deleniti tempora dolorem
          facilis iste? Reprehenderit maxime neque porro optio, animi praesentium laboriosam recusandae! Ex nesciunt maxime dicta quo hic placeat laboriosam possimus totam, ab velit iure quisquam assumenda odit adipisci, eos voluptatum at qui sint aperiam
          blanditiis quos. Quos ratione, molestiae possimus repellendus eveniet et temporibus alias sunt perferendis quod odio, quis tenetur natus obcaecati! Doloremque omnis numquam quia.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-2">
        Content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content-3">
        Content 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">My Footer</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My greatest difficulty is text placement. If I place a text on content-1 for instance, and resize the page's height, the text overlaps behind the footer, exceeds its grid, and even the container grid. Is there any way to fit the text to its "grid area" and resizing it accordingly?

Comment: without HTML its hard to reproduce. The easiest way to fix it however, would be to use an overflow rule.

Comment: @tacoshy I've edited the question. Tried to stick the quesiton to code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting a "fixed" height for your rows. When you say:

```
grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 5.5fr 5.5fr 1fr;
```

it means that once the available height is established, your grid will have a certain height and won't resize according to the text.

My suggestion would be to simply change this line. You could for example just give your header and footer a fixed height:

```
grid-template-rows: 100px auto auto 200px;
```

Comment: there plenty reasons to use a fixed height. Espacially if you want to sue it for apps or in combination with 100vh as the OP does. In that case however you need to add an overflow rule that certain boxes can scroll their content. So you see, a fixed height is not an issue and breaking the design created for 100vh can not be considered as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to add an overflow rule. I just added `.content-1 { overflow-y: auto; }` to your code and you will get now a scrollbar if the text is higher then the box-height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2.409fr 2.409fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 5.5fr 5.5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header sidePanel" 
    "pageContent pageContent sidePanel" 
    "pageContent pageContent sidePanel" 
    "footer footer sidePanel";
}

.content {
  grid-area: pageContent;
  background: #d123;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "content-1 content-2" 
    "content-1 content-3";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.sidePanel {
  grid-area: sidePanel;
}

.content {
  grid-area: pageContent;
}

.content-1 {
  grid-area: content-1;
}

.content-2 {
  grid-area: content-2;
}

.content-3 {
  grid-area: content-3;
}

.content-1,
.content-2,
.content-3 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">My Header</div>
    <div class="sidePanel">My sidePanel</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-1">
        <span class="title">Main Article</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum rem ratione dolorum ducimus quaerat officiis voluptates obcaecati ab illo sequi, blanditiis vel dolore possimus labore asperiores architecto quia nobis accusantium beatae doloremque
          eveniet saepe excepturi laborum exercitationem delectus! Dolor, natus perferendis deleniti sequi veniam. In nemo mollitia dolor ipsam. Ipsa illum delectus eveniet. Explicabo perspiciatis eum distinctio vel quo iure, deleniti tempora dolorem
          facilis iste? Reprehenderit maxime neque porro optio, animi praesentium laboriosam recusandae! Ex nesciunt maxime dicta quo hic placeat laboriosam possimus totam, ab velit iure quisquam assumenda odit adipisci, eos voluptatum at qui sint aperiam
          blanditiis quos. Quos ratione, molestiae possimus repellendus eveniet et temporibus alias sunt perferendis quod odio, quis tenetur natus obcaecati! Doloremque omnis numquam quia.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-2">
        Content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content-3">
        Content 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">My Footer</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```